Ideas to clean and parse data with inconsistent delimiters
I'm working with a list of strings that must be parsed into names and addresses. The issues is that the data was entered by multiple people over the course of 20 years into free text fields. I have been trying to use regex to parse the data but am struggling due to the inconsistency. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Example Data:
Myanmar Wanbao Mining Copper, Ltd., Yangon Office 70 (I)Bo Chein Street Pyay Road, Hlaing Township, Yangon, Burma.

Huawei Technologies (Yangon) Co., Ltd., Yangon, Burma.

KingPai Technology Int'l Co., Limited, 143-6th Street, 1 Town, Linh Xuan Ward, Thu Duc District, Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam.

Narinco, Flat 401-Bin Yas Center—Al Maktum Road, P.O. Box 42340, Dubai, U.A.E.; and Shops 3-4, Sharafia Ahmed Ali Building, al-Nakheel, Deira, Dubai, U.A.E.

Tenco Technology Company Ltd.,—Redd Forest Technology Company Limited; —Shenzhen Shengfaweiye Electronic Co., Ltd.; —Shenzhen Tenco Technology Co., Ltd.; Tenco International Co., Ltd. Room 2709, Block A, Jiahe Huaqiang Building, Shennan Middle Rd., F Shenzhen, Guangdong 518007, China; Room 2709, Block A, Jiahe Building, Shennan Mid Road, Futian District, Shenzhen, 518000, China; Room 311 3F Genplas Industrial Building, 56 Hoi Yuen Road, Kwun Kowloon, Hong Kong; Room 15, 6F Corporation Square, 8 Lam Lok Street, Kowloon Bay, Hong Kong; and Room 801, Number 15, Building 14, Xiayousong Village, Longhua Street, Longhua District, Shenzhen, China 518000.

I have tried making a regex as well as delimiting on html line breaks but there is no consistency throughout the fields.
I have already generated an ID for each record so my goal is to have all the names and all the addresses associated with the same ID but in its own field.

Good luck, this is not a simple project. It's essentially a limited form of natural language processing, so look for NLP libraries designed for processing address information.

That is what I was concerned about. I've never used NLP but have played around with it for this problem but ran into issues with identifying the company names as well. My other thought is to create a simple gui that would let me categorize and parse manually since this is only about 3000 rows.
